# Can I achieve variable padding character and variable width with my beloved % formatter?

Tags: python

I may be dating myself here, but nonetheless grew up with the % formatter in C, and never really learned the new iostream stuff in C++.  As python had the % operator, I never bothered to learn the power of the format operator.  However, it appears I may have hit a brick wall with my beloved % formatter.

I would like to "zeropad" a number with both a variable character (not the zero character) and a variable width.  It looks like the format methods handle this quite well:

```
width = 10
base = 'd'
fill = '1'
{0:{fill}>{width}{base}}'.format(43, base=base,fill=fill, width=width)
```

I cannot figure out how to get this to work using the % formatter!  Help!

```
'%013d'%(43) #works, but will not "work" for %513d where 5 should be the pad character
'%0*d'%(13,43) #as does this, but
'%a13d'%(43) #does not fill with a
```

I know there are workarounds to achieve this, but is there something really simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magical trick to the `%` operator that you're missing, but you can do what you want with [str.ljust and str.rjust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust)

```
>>> # Pad the number 15 with zeros, up to 10 positions.
>>> ("%d" % 15).rjust(10, "0")
'0000000015'
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use arbitrary fill characters with the old `%` string formatter, *full stop*. The format *only* support specifying a variable width with the `*` character, that's it.

Padding can be done with spaces, or zeros, nothing else. You'd have to use the [`str.rjust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust), [`str.ljust()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) and [`str.center()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) methods if you wanted to pad with something else, a cumbersome task.

You can generate the formatter in two steps:

```
format = '%%%(flag)s%(width)s%(base)s' % dict(base=base, flag=flag, width=width)
```

provided that `fill` is an empty string, or `'-'`, `'0'`, `'#'`, `'+'` or `' '` to switch between formatting flags; `'0'` is the zero-padding option.

The second step then uses the output of that to format:

```
format % (43)
```

The new `str.format()` uses multiple passes internally instead, allowing you to interpolate parameters into placeholders more easily, *and* supports more formats, padding and other features.

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything, there are only a few conversion flag characters available as is documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Namely:

- '#'  The value conversion will use the “alternate form” (where defined below).
- '0'  The conversion will be zero padded for numeric values.
- '-'  The converted value is left adjusted (overrides the '0' conversion if both are given).
- ' '  (a space) A blank should be left before a positive number (or empty string) produced by a signed conversion.
- '+'  A sign character ('+' or '-') will precede the conversion (overrides a “space” flag).

Trying to pad with a `1` as you are doing right here is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, you have to format it twice. And it gets messy:

```
>>> ('%%0%dd' % width) % 43
'0000000043'
```